# Codeigniter build validation class at your own needs

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, frameworks, codeigniter-2

I am working in codeigniter and Iam looking to make my own custom validation class using "Validation_form" library and my custom rule where I will place my own validation rules and use that from everywhere in my project, but this seems impossible, I tried in couples ways to handle this but nothing.

Codeigniter kindle force me to make my callback methods in my controller but I need them in my library or "method" or wherever else!!!

My question is, can I build an specific library where I'll place my validation rules and other functions I need to handle that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could create a new library in `application/libriries` and name the file `MY_Form_validation`

What you are doing here is extending the `form_validation` class so that you will not need to mess with the core files.

The `MY_` is what is set on your config, be sure to check it if you changed yours.

sample **MY_Form_validation.php**

```
class MY_Form_validation Extends CI_Form_validation
{
   //this is mandatory for this class
   //do not forget this or it will not work
   public function __construct($rules = array(){
        parent::__construct($rules);
        $this->CI->lang->load('MY_form_validation');
    }
   public function method1($str){
     return $str == '' ? FALSE : TRUE;
   }
   pulic function method2($str)
   {
       //if you want a validation from database
       //you can load it here
       // or check the `form_validation` file on `system/libraries/form_validation`

  }

  public function check_something_with_post($tr)
  {
      return $this->CI->input->post('some_post') == FALSE ? FALSE : TRUE;
  }
}
```

Basically, when you call a rule sample `method1|method2` the value of your post field will be the parameter of the method. if you want to check other post you can do it by using `$this->CI->input->post('name of the post');`

when you want to pass a parameter just look at the form validation `is_unique` or `unique` code on `system/libraries/form_validation` you will have an idea.

To create a error message that goes with it go to `application/language/english/MY_Form_validation_lang`

Sample `MY_form_validation_lang.php`

```
$lang['method1'] = "error error error.";
$lang['method2'] = "this is an error message.";
```

if `english` does not exist on your `application/language` just create it.

check more at[**Creating libraries**](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html)

**NOTE:**

On some `linux` or `debian` server you may want to change the file name from `MY_Form_validation` to
`MY_form_validation` note the small **f** on the word `form`.