# Codeigniter using form validation function "matches" with sub-array POST

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

Just started with CI last week and got this issue. What to put inside the `matches` function if I'm passing the form data as an array?

I use array in the html form to locate all input fields inside single array in case I want to pass user generated input such as multiple phone numbers or emails. So everything is placed in array such as this:

```
    <div>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="input[password]" id="password" value="<?php echo set_value("input[password]")?>"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="password">Confirm Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="input[conf_password]" id="conf_password" value="<?php echo set_value("input[conf_password]")?>"/>
    </div>
```

**Notice the `*name="input[password]"*`**

The validation works like a charm for all except when I use the function `matches`:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules("input[password]", "Password", 'required|matches[input[conf_password]]');

$this->form_validation->set_rules("input[conf_password]", "Confirm Password", 'required');

matches[input[conf_password]]
```

This will not work because after I checked the Form_Validation.php I found out that `matches` will take whatever string I put between the square brackets of `matches` and tries to fetch the value from `$_POST` directly.

CI codes:

```
/**
     * Match one field to another
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   string
     * @param   field
     * @return  bool
     */
    public function matches($str, $field)
    {
        if ( ! isset($_POST[$field]))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }   
        $field = $_POST[$field];    
        return ($str !== $field) ? FALSE : TRUE;
    }
```

So by right there would be no such thing as `$_POST[input[conf_password]]`.

I'm aware that I can solve this by using

1. custom validation function
2. compare directly $_POST["input"]["password"] === $_POST["input"]["conf_password"]

I'm not sure what I'm missing since everything in CI related to forms is working nicely with arrays, why wouldn't this function?

Comment: return `!($str !== $field)`

Comment: Actually it will return false in the if ! isset($_POST[$field])

Comment: I was thinking of another way to write that, not relevant to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, i have a similar problem and there is no way CI core input can solve that, I solved mine not by creating a custom callback function it clutters the controller often, but by extending the `Form_validation` class **MY_Form_validation**

then i created a function which i called `matches_array` then used as 
`matches_array[inputkeyname---inputkeyvalue]`

os you would write yours as

```
$this>form_validation>set_rules("input[password]","Password",'required|matches_array[input---conf_password]');
```

Here is the function as i remember it.

```
public function matches_array($str, $field)
{
    $field = explode('---',$field);
    if ( ! isset($theField = $_POST [$field[0] ][ $field[1] ]))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }  
    return ($str !== $theField) ? FALSE : TRUE;
}
```

**EDIT**

Put it on your `app/libraries` and name it `MY_Form_validation`, `MY_` is what you defined in your config. anything you put in here will be automatically added to the `rules`.

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation 
{

    public function __construct($rules = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($rules);
        $this->CI->lang->load('MY_form_validation');
    }

    //your custom functions
}
```

Comment: +1 seems like a good idea. Where did you put your MY_CI_Input?

Comment: look at my edit, i have a similar answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21046166/codeigniter-build-validation-class-at-your-own-needs/21046274#21046274

sorry it was `CI_Form_validation` not `CI_Input` i changed my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can Edit MY_Form_validation

```
public function matches($str, $field)

    {
        return isset($this->_field_data[$field], $this->_field_data[$field]['postdata'])
        ? ($str === $this->_field_data[$field]['postdata'])
        : FALSE;
    }
```

Comment: Did you actually run this code or your just pulled it out of your head?